# Parse XML with single id and multiple values - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

```
String var = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<current func = "123" name="lllo" add="pol" ..... />";
```

getting this xml need to get the values stored in this xml

I have tried xmlparser to get valeus
as

```
    String func= 123;
    String name = lllo;
..........
```

How can be possible? need help

Updated : I tried this getting null:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser pullParser = factory.newPullParser();
InputStream is =
        new ByteArrayInputStream(newString.getBytes());
pullParser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");

String min = pullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "uid");
String max = pullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ":" + min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
System.out.println(":" + min + "" + max);
```

Comment: If you've tried it, then presumably you've got some code, and an incorrect result. Please present those.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see my above result ... getting null values

Comment: Well you've never called `next()` to actually get it to parse anything, so I'm not surprised. You should call `next()` until you get to the root element.

Comment: Read here please: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: tnx . @elefasGR , But this is for <foo>Hello World!</foo> Not for this <current func = "123" name="lllo" add="pol" ..... />";

Comment: It's really important that you learn to read documentation and understand it. Yes, the example given *happened* to parse that text - but did you try it for the text you've got? What would you expect to happen? What did happen when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure here is a standalone snippet working as you expected:

```
public class SimpleXmlPullApp
{

    public static void main (String args[])
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<current func = \"123\" name=\"lllo\" add=\"pol\" />" ) );
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                for(int i=0; i<xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Attribute name: " + xpp.getAttributeName(i) + " - Attribute value: " + xpp.getAttributeValue(i));
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
}
```

running this will output:

```
Attribute name: func - Attribute value: 123
Attribute name: name - Attribute value: lllo
Attribute name: add - Attribute value: pol
```